# Extract Spring Boot User Properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hey guys I have been trying to determine which properties in Spring boot were configured by users vs. spring auto-configuration.  I am able to list all properties, but I am not certain how to just get the properties declared by the user.

//This method gets all properties in the Spring environment

```
public Properties getSpringEnvironmentProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    MutablePropertySources propSrcs = ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources();
    StreamSupport.stream(propSrcs.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(ps -> ps instanceof EnumerablePropertySource)
        .map(ps -> ((EnumerablePropertySource) ps).getPropertyNames())
        .flatMap(Arrays::<String>stream)
        .forEach(propName -> props.setProperty(propName, env.getProperty(propName)));
    return props;
  }
```

Is there any way to only get properties that are user declared in files like:  application.properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @ConfigurationProperties for the Complex Properties file, following the steps:

Step 1: Create application.properties which store these properties

```
#App
app.menus[0].label=Home
app.menus[0].path=/
app.menus[1].label=Java Core
app.menus[1].path=/javacore
app.menus[2].label=Spring
app.menus[2].path=/spring
```

Step 2: Declare java properties class

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class AppProperties {

    private List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<Menu>();
    //do stuff
}
```

Step 3: Inject properties into your service

```
private AppProperties app;
```

You can find the working example from the post [Spring boot configuration properties example](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-configuration-properties-example.html)

Hope this help!

Comment: While that works when I am the writer of the application, that doesn't work when I am writing a starter.  I don't know the names of the property files that the user will use.

Comment: Your case makes me confused. Because if you can't control your properties they might override the existing system properties

Comment: That is expected.  I am effectively writing a Spring Boot starter that parses all the user created properties and offers that information as a Rest Endpoint by default.  (Similar in concept to Actuator)